# Restrict Ansible script module using sudoers on the remote node

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that performs some prechecks on the database as the Oracle user. The remote node is an AIX server and so I created a shell script that is ran via the playbook.

```
---
- hosts: db
  var_files:
    - ansible_var.yml

  tasks:
    - name: "DB Checks"
    become: True
    become_user: oracle
    script: "{ db_prechk }"
```

On the AIX server, I added the below entry to the sudoers file

```
 ansible ALL=(oracle) NOPASSWD: /tmp/ansible-tmp-*/db_prechecks.sh
```

But the playbook fails with the error that it's waiting for the privilege escalation prompt.

This runs fine if it is ran as root. However we do not want passwordless root between the Ansible controller and the remote nodes. So we created ansible user on the controller and remote nodes and exchanged the SSH keys.

This also runs if the sudoers entry is just

```
ansible ALL=(oracle) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

We do not want to provide full access to the `oracle` userid via the `ansible` user id too.

I ran the playbook in the verbose mode and can see that Ansible is copying the script to the `remote_tmp` dir and is executing it as the `oracle` userid. In that case the sudoers line should've allowed it to run?

Comment: Sometimes /tmp is mounted with noexec.  Look at /etc/fstab

Comment: @bodo That would not explain why it worked with `NOPASSWD: ALL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the verbose mode output, you will see that the actual command differs from the one you specified in the `sudoers` file:

> <127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC ssh -o ForwardAgent=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=2202 -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/techraf/devops/testground/debian/.vagrant/machines/debian/virtualbox/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ansible -o ConnectTimeout=120 -o ControlPath=/Users/techraf/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt 127.0.0.1 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'**sudo -H -S -n -u oracle /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-xoamupogqwtteubvedoscaghzmfascsr;  /tmp/ansible-tmp-1488508771.72-271591203197790/db_prechecks.sh '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'** && sleep 0'"'"''

So what is executed after `sudo -u oracle` starts actually with `/bin/sh -c`.

I managed to filter a working string to:

```
ansible ALL=(oracle) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS*; * /tmp/ansible-tmp-*/db_prechecks.sh*
```

But it is based on trial-and-error. I'm not sure yet why `*` is required between `;` and `/tmp/...` and at the end, but otherwise it does not work.

In both places Ansible added superfluous space characters and it seems to be the reason, as adding a space to a shell command (specified in the `sudoers` file) does affect the ability to `sudo`.

<sup>You might try with `?` instead of `*`, I will test later</sup>

Comment: I tried using `?` and `[a-z]`, but it's not working. I reverted back to the `*` and will keep checking

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"This also runs if the sudoers entry is just `ansible ALL=(oracle) NOPASSWD: ALL`"*

A: Quoting from [Privilege escalation must be general](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general):

> *"You cannot limit privilege escalation permissions to certain commands..."*

Answer (score 0):

Replying to @techraf's answer: sudo seems to truncate the extra space and you can see it with `sudo -l`. I was able to get around this by escaping the spaces with `\` as instructed in sudo's man page:

> \x        For any character ‘x’, evaluates to ‘x’.