# Passwordless sudo with limited grants in sudoers file using Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I'm implementing a small playbook to install some apt-packages to my machines, e.g. docker, git.

Here's an example task:

```
- name: "Docker: install various dependencies"
  become: true
  tags:
    - docker_installation
  apt:
    #  force_apt_get: true # didnt help
    name: "apt-transport-https, ca-certificates, curl, software-properties-common"
    update_cache: true
    state: present
```

Since I want to use passwordless sudo I've created a dedicated user *ansible* on the target hosts that will execute the playbook-tasks. I'm trying to achieve that the ansible user is only allowed to execute the commands **that are necessary for the playbook** without being asked for a password.

Therefore I edited the sudoers file like the following (only showing non-defaults):

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
ansible ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-cache, /usr/bin/apt-get update install, /usr/bin/apt
```

When I ssh on the target host as user ansible, I can execute the apt-related commands as expected without being prompted for a password. However when I execute the playbook, it fails and states:

> Escalation requires password

```
fatal: [elk-dummy]: FAILED! => {
"msg": "Missing sudo password"
}
```

When I change the sudoers entry to

```
ansible ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

everything works fine.

Looking at this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555677/restrict-ansible-script-module-using-sudoers-on-the-remote-node) I was hoping to get some information from the logs but I dont know how to handle this message/cause:

> <192.168.2.35> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
>
> <192.168.2.35> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/lukas/.ansible/cp/0e1063962c 192.168.2.35 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1576966035.82-40405969615486/ /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1576966035.82-40405969615486/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
>
> <192.168.2.35> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
>
> <192.168.2.35> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/lukas/.ansible/cp/0e1063962c -tt 192.168.2.35 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-nsmqtlltfzcxfvlapewjxgvqsbjfhzlc ; /usr/bin/python3 /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1576966035.82-40405969615486/AnsiballZ_command.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''

I've already looked at the python code of the apt-module searching for other commands that will get executed for the apt-module but I couldn't find any.

Any help on achieving this is much appreciated!

I'm running ansible version 2.9.2. The target host runs on Ubuntu server 18.04.

Comment: If you chose to use the **shell** module rather than the **apt** one you could easily achieve this; the problem with your sudoers entry would then be that you'd need a literal entry for each subcommand, you can't lump them together like `/usr/bin/apt-get update install`  ... look at e.g.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279125/allow-user-to-run-a-command-with-arguments-which-contains-spaces/279126

Comment: @jww: One might argue its' [a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). But, generally, Is system management an SW development? Some topics might fit better this category than others. To avoid these disputes it should be explicit. System management questions go to SO or not? At the moment there are 10k Puppet, 19k Chef and 32k Ansible questions at SO.

Comment: @jww: Searching SO "python sudoers NOPASSWD ALL" there are another 35 candidates to be closed. This time with Python.

Comment: @jww: I dont understand the downvote at all. First of all as Vladimir Botka stated, there are plenty of Ansible-related questions on SO. Is Ansible/Puppet/Chef not also referred as **infrastructure as code**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"When I change the sudoers entry to `ansible ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: ALL` everything works fine."*

A: Quoting from [Privilege escalation must be general](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general):

> *"You cannot limit privilege escalation permissions to certain commands... "*

Comment: Thanks a lot! So that means that the user that is running the playbook always needs all grants? Is there another way to limit them?

Comment: Yes. All grants are needed. I'm not aware of any way to limit them. I can't imagine maintaining the hypothetical sets of limited privileges for certain tasks.

Comment: While the documentation is correct out of the box there's nothing to stop one from finding out which executables/modules ansible actually executes on the remote host and narrow things down to the few things one want to permit with specific sudoers lines;  if one doesn't want to worry about which version of ansible on which version of debian/ubuntu/... one is using one could even go down the route of using the **shell**  module and make sure the things one wants to permit explicitly.

Comment: Right. Still the same. I can't imagine maintaining the hypothetical sets of limited privileges for certain tasks.