# Ansible - Do we need to configure sudo with root access on all hosts?

Tags: linux, ansible

I have a simple ansible testing playbook to run on the locahost and on one remote host.
The playbook runs linux command "pvs" which needs to run as root.
I have become=true in ansible.cfg.
On localhost user test1 is configured in /etc/sudoers with "ugly" ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL - because apparently no other solution to launch commands as root in batch mode, without providing the password, As confirms Vladimir :
[Restrict Ansible script module using sudoers on the remote node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555677/restrict-ansible-script-module-using-sudoers-on-the-remote-node)
(I can do Cmnd_Alias, but in the end, ansible need /bin/sh .. so no point to limit it with other commands)
And, when I run the below playbook, I have to configure the same sudoers config in remote machine as well.
Does this mean, that on all the machines we manage, we need to have this "ansible" user to have root access via sudo? I hope not, otherwise this is a VERY BIG security concern..
Do you have any advice workaround or an idea to share with me to limit root access?

### my ansible.cfg :

```
[privilege_escalation]
become                  = true # (this I need otherwise command  "pvs" will not run)
become_method           = sudo
become_user             = root
become_ask_pass         = false # (this also I need, do not want any manuel providing)
default_become          = true
```

### Playbook :

```
 1 ---
  2 - name: test remote machine connection
  3   #hosts: localhost
  4   hosts: all
  5   gather_facts: no
  6
  7   tasks:
  8     - name: get physical volumes
  9       #shell: pvs # OK for localhost, but NOT for remote host, as sudo is not configured
 10       #command:   # Same as above for remote host : "Missing sudo password"
 11         #cmd: pvs
 12       raw: pvs    # Same as above for remote host : "Missing sudo password"
 13       register: output
 14
 15     - name: Show output
 16       debug:
 17         msg: "{{ output.stdout }}"
 18
```

### Result:

```
PLAY [test remote machine connection] *************************************************************************************

TASK [get physical volumes] *******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [sh2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Show output] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "  PV         VG             Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  \n  /dev/xvdc  prdvvg         lvm2 a--  <10.00g  <2.00g\n  /dev/xvde  prdvvg         lvm2 a--  <10.00g <10.00g\n  /dev/xvdf  clone_prdtm1vg lvm2 a--  <10.00g  <2.00g\n  /dev/xvdg  clone_prdtm1vg lvm2 a--  <10.00g <10.00g\n"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
sh2                        : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Thank you

Comment: If you expect `ansible` to perform tasks that require `root` access, then `ansible` needs root privileges, either via `sudo` or via appropriate `ssh` credentials to the `root` account. You can't restrict Ansible to particular commands because Ansible isn't running specific commands; it's running (typically) `python`. If you need more granular access control, you'll need to look at other tools (or limit yourself to using ansible's `raw` module, I guess).

Comment: Thanks larsks, But sorry, as I show you even raw module does not work.  I believe this problem  is something that RedHat Ansible should improve, as they boast Ansible as swiss knife for automation... but can be dangerous. Of course while managing a big park of servers we need root to pass some commands, but I thought Ansible would provide something more for security...Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you really afraid of having user account with nopasswd sudo, there are few options:

- Use pam_ssh [1] to use ssh agent (passed by Ansible from  a controller to the target host) to have passwordless sudo. It won't protect your host from your controller, but at least, local processes from random users can't self-escalate.
- Use special account for ansible where no one else can run anything (basically, proxy to root), or just configure server as root. It's pretty easy: create a user with ssh-only access via ssh key (no password), and allow this user to have passwordless sudo. The sudoers.d snippet would looks like this: `specialuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. The weak protection here is that no one on the host can become `specialuser` without been a root, and only ansible controller has access to the private key for that `specialuser`. It's all not impenetrable, but at least your `qemu` user no longer can become a root through simple sudo call.
- You may try to find alternative transports for ansible (aka connection plugins), but it's going to be mostly vaporware for you concern, as the problem is that ansible can do whatever it wants.

So, either pam_ssh for sudo, or dedicated user for ansible.

[1] https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Pam_ssh_agent_auth

Comment: Hi George, Thanks for this.  Yes, pam_ssh seems to be a good solution/workaround for me. I'm more interested in "Use special account for ansible where no one else can run anything (basically, proxy to root), or just configure server as root." - But I do not understand what you meant; This is what I try to achieve, actually; A special user only for ansible; I do not know if you have few minutes for me, to explain your suggestion. What I do not get is "no one else can run anything .."; Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly I don't think there is an option executing commands which needs root-privileges without the sudoers file.

As [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555677/restrict-ansible-script-module-using-sudoers-on-the-remote-node) you could only permit, the one specific command you want to execute. This could like the following line:

```
ansible ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS*; * pvs
```

A further option to increase security, in case you didn't yet, is to create a specific ansible-user on every host and authenticate only via SSH private/public key allowed from one specific host.

Comment: Hi lugoll, Thanks for taking time to answer, But your answer is not a one :( It asks for the passwd first of all; And then this is exactly what I would like to avoid, having /bin/sh or any "*" in sudoers. Also, you should first tes your answers before posting ;)